# Solving compound assignment expressions

Tags: c

Okay, I know the output for the expression (x *= y = z = 4;) is 40; but how exactly did we get 40? Can you please show me step by step.

I thought the precedence is from right to left so (2 * 4) = (z =4), I don't understand

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define PRINTX printf("%d\n",x)

int main (void){
    int x = 2, y, z;
    x *= 3 + 2;
    PRINTX;
    x *= y = z = 4;
    PRINTX;
    x = y == z;
    PRINTX;
    x == ( y = z );
    PRINTX;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good question by the way.

Answer (score 4):

No, the only way that assignment can be evaluated here is right to left.

First, note that `x *= 99`, for example, is shorthand for `x = x * 99`.

With that said,

```
x *= y = z = 4;
```

is equivalent to

```
z = 4;
y = z;
x *= y; // This is shorthand for x = x * 4
```

Consider what would happen if you tried to evaluate it the other way around:

```
// y is unininitialized
x *= y;
y = z;
z = 4;
```

It would fail.

So really,

```
// x = 2
int x = 2, y, z;
// x = x * (3 + 2) = x * 5 = 2 * 5 = 10
x *= 3 + 2;

// x = x * 4 = 10 * 4 = 40
x *= y = z = 4;
```

This can be rewritten as

```
int x, y, z;
x = 2; // x = 2
x = x * (3 + 2); // This is 2 * 5, so x = 10 after this

z = 4; // z = 4
y = z; // y = 4
x = x * y; // x = 10 * 4 = 40
```

And that's how you end up with 40.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm very confused. Where did you get the 5 from? I thought it was x * 4 and where did x *= 3 * 2; come from

Comment: @nonameisbetter I updated. The `5` comes from `3 + 2`. `x *= 3 + 2` is equivalent to `x *= (3 + 2)`, which is equivalent to `x *= 5`.

Answer (score 3):

All of the assignment operators have equal precedence, and right-to-left associativity (which affects what happens when multiple operators of equal precedence are present in an expression).

This means `x *= y = z = 4` is equivalent to `x *= (y = (z = 4))`.   `z = 4` must be evaluated first (which assigns `z` to `4`, and gives a result of `4`).   The assignment `y = ...` then gives the value `y` the value of `4`, and also produces a result of `4`.   The assignment `x *= ...` then multiples `x` (which has a value `10`) by `4`, giving a result of `40`.

(The reason `x *= 3 + 2` gives `x` the value `10` is that addition has higher precedence than assignment, so `x *= 3+2` is equivalent to `x *= (3 + 2)` rather than `(x *= 3) + 2`.)

If the assignment operators were instead left-to-right associative, `x *= y = z = 4` would be equivalent to `(((x *= y) = y) = z) = 4` which would not compile.

Answer (score 2):

You have:

```
int x = 2, y, z;
x *= 3 + 2;
```

This is a shorthand for `x = x * (3 + 2)`, which evaluates to `10` given that `x` starts at `2`.

```
PRINTX;
x *= y = z = 4;
```

After this, `y == z` and both are set to `4`; and `x` is 4 times its previous value of `10`, hence `40`.

```
PRINTX;
x = y == z;
```

This compares `y` and `z`; they're equal, so `x` is assigned `1` (comparisons always evaluate to `0` or `1`).

```
PRINTX;
x == ( y = z );
```

This assigns `z` to `y` (leaving the value unchanged at `4`); nominally, this is compared with `x` but the compiler can ignore the comparison.  Therefore, `x` is unchanged and still `1`.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan. I guess the confusion on my part was I didn't know the question wanted us to evaluate the entire expression as a whole. I thought it was line by line

Comment: @nonameisbetter A lot of programming languages have shorthand like this - sometimes it can be helpful to try to expand it to its equivalent "longer" version if the shorthand's confusing. I think that this is a case where the shorthand doesn't help because it makes the code more difficult to read.

Comment: @EJoshuaS: The code is lousy code — it's only purpose is pedagogic, to test whether you, the reader, understand the rules of the language.  If someone presented me with code to review like this, I'd send them away with an earful, or educate them on the error of their ways, or otherwise do my utmost to prevent it from appearing in the main code.  Mixing any `op=` assignment with plain assignments is pretty ugly.  Since all the numbers are fixed here, the computation can all be done at compile time. The compiler could reduce the code to a series of 4 calls to `printf()` with precomputed values.